# php - need help converting a python command to php code

Tags: php, python, md5, hashlib

I'm using the python hashlib to get a condensed md5 value using the following command, can someone help me out with a compatible function?

```
hashlib.md5('my string').hexdigest()
```

Comment: md5('my string') works in php. not sure regarding the hexdigest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = 'my string'
$encoded_string = md5($string);
```

Comment: that provides just the md5 string, I'm looking for hixdigest which condenses the md5 string

Comment: This solution gives the same result as your python line. Python: http://ideone.com/brDJ7 php: http://ideone.com/J7vY9 What other do you want to achieve?

Comment: my mistake! I was looking at the wrong record in the database, which had a different shorter hash so I initially thought there was a difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo md5('apple');
// => 1f3870be274f6c49b3e31a0c6728957f
```

produces the same result as

```
require 'digest/md5';
print Digest::MD5.hexdigest('apple');
# => 1f3870be274f6c49b3e31a0c6728957f
```